# Complex derivatives of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have a question about how to calculate a complex derivative. For example, I don't understand the following equations:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\frac{1-z\bar{z}}{(e^{it}-z)(e^{-it}-\bar{z})})=\frac{1}{e^{-it}-\bar{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\frac{1-z\bar{z}}{e^{it}-z})=\frac{1}{e^{-it}-\bar{z}}\frac{e^{it}(e^{-it}-\bar{z})}{(e^{it}-z)^2}$. Can someone explain me please those two equations? I actually thought that $\bar{z}$ is not differentiable but that seems not correct, I don't know.

Comment: First read  [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) wikipedia article on  Wirtinger derivatives.

Comment: Thank you, I already read that but I think they say nothing about the derivative of $\bar{z}$?

Comment: Could someone explain me please those two equations? I'm trying to understand but it does not go well..

Comment: Here we talk about partial derivatives in the new variables $z, \bar z$ which are independent, so the above differentiation is correct; if it helps replace $\bar z$ with another name like $w$ and then differentiate the above as you do it formally in two independent variables $z,w$ and then replace back $w$ with $\bar z$;

Comment: Thank you, but I think $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are not indepedent? There is a strong relation between both, right?

Comment: @Conrad, you mean that we can see $\bar{z}$ as a constant if we differentiate to $z$? Why is that? We have $z=a+ib$ then $\bar{z}=a-ib$ so they aren't independent at all in my eyes?

Comment: they are independent as "real variables" - technically you need to think of them as linear differential operators in the variable $x,y$, let's call them $2L_z=\frac {\partial}{\partial y}-i\frac {\partial}{\partial y}, 2L_{\bar z}=...$ and by definition, they do satisfy $L_z(\bar z)=L_z(x-iy)=0, L_{\bar z}(x+iy)=0$ so that is what you actually do when you apply $\frac {\partial}{\partial z}$ is applying $L_z$ and indeed you get that applies to $\bar z$ to be $0$ as noted here

Comment: Thanks! You mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ I suppose in the first term of $L_z$?

Comment: A big thank you for the help

Comment: Yes for $L_z$ it is with $x$ - anyway happy to be of help and hopefully now it is clearer